# MIPS bubble sort algorithm not printing

Tags: mips, bubble-sort

I am currently beginning to study the MIPS language and I am trying to write a bubble sort code in MIPS, but I guess I have made a mistake somewhere and i can't seem to find it. I believe I am storing elements properly but I don't know why it is not working. Here is a picture of my code:

```
.data
array: .space 100
i: .word 0
j: .word 0
temp: .word 
.text
la $s2, i
la $s3, j
la $s4, temp
li $v0,5
syscall
move $s0, $v0 #array size
li $v0, 8
la $a0, array
li $a1, 100
move $s1, $a0 #actual array(with elements)
syscall
move $a0, $s0 #size becomes argument
move $a1, $s1 #array becomes argument
jal BubbleSort
li $v0, 4
move $a0, $v0
syscall
li $v0, 10
syscall
BubbleSort:
move $s0, $a0
move $s1, $a1
j ExternalLoop
ExternalLoop:
slt $t0,$s2, $s0 #for(i=0;I<N;i++)
beq $t0, $zero, ExitLoop
j InternalLoop
addi $s2, $s2,1 #i++
li $s3, 0 #reset j after every iteration
InternalLoop:
slt $t1, $s3, $s0 #for(j=0;J<N;j++)
beq $t1, $zero, ExitLoop
#array[j]=s1+4*j :
#sll $t2, $s3, 2
#add $s1, $s1, $t2
lb $t3, 0($s1) #array[j]
lb $t4, 4($s1) #array[j+1]
#swapping:
move $s4, $t3
move $t3, $t4
move $t4, $s4
sb $t5, 0($t3)
addi $s3, $s3, 1 #j++
j InternalLoop
move $v0, $t5
ExitLoop:
jr $ra
```

Maybe my mistake is somewhere at the end where I am storing the return values but I don't know. Can anyone help?

Comment: [do not put images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714). Just copy and paste here

Comment: Thank you for your comment.